# Why in ReactJS using Hooks, onClick={forceUpdate} can work?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

If we have

```
  const [, forceUpdate] = useState(0);

  function handleClick() {
    forceUpdate();
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>{Math.random()}</div>
     
      <button onClick={handleClick}>click</button>
```

then it doesn't do the force update. Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-meadow-9icnh?file=/src/App.js

But if it is

```
      <button onClick={forceUpdate}>click</button>
```

Then it works.  Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-germain-n0trr?file=/src/App.js

What is the reason for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your `forceUpdate` is taking the `event`(**React's Synthetic event**) object that's being implicitly passed to it and setting it as state. In other cases, doing `forceUpdate` with no args is equivalent to passing `undefined` and it being a primitive will not cause the re-render again for subsequent state updates.

Changing `handleClick(..)` to the below will result in same :-

```
function handleClick(e) {
    forceUpdate(e);
  }
```

Comment: ah, I forgot the subtle event object

Comment: @nonopolarity If you want a forceUpdate that doesn't require an argument you can use this: `const [ , forceUpdate ] = useReducer(() => ({}), 0);`

Comment: @Paul a new object every time

Comment: Yes, the useReducer version constructs a new empty object each call rather than needing to be provided with a new object (`e`). You could alternatively use a counter, which is what the [React FAQ suggests](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-forceupdate): `const [ , forceUpdate] = useReducer(x => x + 1, 0);`